# Indy HTTP Server URL-encoded request

Tags: http, encoding, indy

When Indy `TIdHTTPServer` gets a request with a URL like `/find?location=%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82` (UTF-8 url-encoded value), the `location` field in `RequestInfo.Params` has an unreadable value `Ñ‚ÐµÑÑ‚`.

How to get a readable value?

I'm using Indy 10.6.0.4975.

Answer (score 3):

`TIdHTTPServer` currently parses input parameters using the charset specified in the `Content-Type` request header, and if there is no charset specified than Indy's 8bit encoding is used instead. This is a known limitation of `TIdHTTPServer` as there is currently no option to tell it to decode the parameters using a user-defined charset.  So you will have to manually parse the `ARequestInfo.QueryParams` and/or `ARequestInfo.UnparsedParams` property, such as by calling `TIdURI.URLDecode()` directly with a UTF-8 encoding in its `AByteEncoding` parameter, eg:

```
procedure MyDecodeAndSetParams(ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo);
var
  i, j : Integer;
  value: s: string;
  LEncoding: IIdTextEncoding;
begin
  if IsHeaderMediaType(ARequestInfo.ContentType, 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded') then
  begin
    value := ARequestInfo.FormParams;
    if ARequestInfo.CharSet <> '' then
      LEncoding := CharsetToEncoding(ARequestInfo.CharSet)
    else
      LEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
  end else
  begin
    value := ARequestInfo.QueryParams;
    LEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
  end;

  ARequestInfo.Params.BeginUpdate;
  try
    ARequestInfo.Params.Clear;
    i := 1;
    while i <= Length(value) do
    begin
      j := i;
      while (j <= Length(value)) and (value[j] <> '&') do
      begin
        Inc(j);
      end;
      s := StringReplace(Copy(value, i, j-i), '+', ' ', [rfReplaceAll]);
      ARequestInfo.Params.Add(TIdURI.URLDecode(s, LEncoding));
      i := j + 1;
    end;
  finally
    ARequestInfo.Params.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  MyDecodeAndSetParams(ARequestInfo);
  ...
end;
```

**UPDATE:** Since February 2021, `TIdHTTPServer` now defaults to parsing input parameters using UTF-8 if no charset is specified in the `Content-Type` header.  So the above workaround is no longer needed.

**UPDATE:** If you still need to use the above workaround in older versions, I have updated the code to now default to UTF-8 if `ARequestInfo.CharSet` is blank when parsing `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: GIdDefaultTextEncoding:=encUTF8 has no effect.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I didn't notice that `CharsetToEncoding()` (which `DecodeAndSetParams()` uses internally) forces 8bit for a blank charset instead of using `GIdDefaultTextEncoding`.  I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: your code will work incorrectly if client send urlencoded post-form with url params. but thanks for idea

Comment: URL params and Form params should be treated separately. It is actually a mistake that TIdHTTPServer merges them together, and that will be corrected in Indy 11. There is nothing stopping you from merging them together in the above code if you really need to.