# Delphi7 Indy HTTPServer not getting form parameters

Tags: html, delphi, indy

I have an Indy 10 IdHTTPServer in a Windows application which serves a virtual HTML form with two text boxes and a submit button. When the button is pressed in the browser I am not seeing any form params returned to the server. 
Note that this is a bit of proof of concept code which will be used to make a windows service respond to button presses in a web form.

The HTML form is like this:

```
 <form action="http://<addressofsite>/" method="post">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

in the Delphi code I have this:

```
procedure TForm1.HTTPServer1CommandGet(AThread: TIdPeerThread;
 ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin

...  

 if ARequestInfo.Command = 'POST' then
    begin
      {******* POSTS ***************}
      Memo1.Text := ARequestInfo.RawHTTPCommand;
    end;
end;
```

I have tried various bits of the ARequestInfo structure but whatever I try all I see when the button is pressed in the browser is:

POST / HTTP 1.1

No params appear to be passed.

I'm obviously doing something wrong, so please can someone point out my idiocy.

Update:

As pointed out by The Arioch below, I should have checked that the browser is actually sending the data - so using Chrome developer tools I examined the headers, the results of which are:

```
Response Headers

  Connection:close
  Content-Type:text/html
  Server:Indy/10.0.52

Request Headers

  Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image  /webp,*/*;q=0.8
  Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
  Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
  Authorization:Basic YWRtaW46cGFzcw==
  Cache-Control:max-age=0
  Connection:keep-alive
  Content-Length:31
  Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  Host:127.0.0.1:8091
  Origin:http://127.0.0.1:8091
  Referer:http://127.0.0.1:8091/main
  Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
  User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36      (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36

Form Data

  firstname:Mickey
  lastname:Mouse
```

So the browser is definitely sending the form data.

Comment: did you intercepted what your browser did sent actually ? did the browser sent all those parameters or not ? Set some HTTP monitoring proxy or HTTP sniffer and run your browser through it, and see if the parameters really where there

Comment: @The Arioch. Thanks, I used Chrome developer tools to examine the request headers, and the form data is in there:

Comment: But it is not in HTTP headers - it should be in HTTP content !!!  Did you read Wikipedia what is difference between GET and POST forms ?

Comment: @The Arioch. Sorry, poorly phrased, I just meant that the form data is visible in the browser request, see above.

Comment: The RawHTTPCommand property does not contain form parameters. TIdHTTPRequestInfo has properties for request parameters.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24875418/6517492

Comment: You are using a very old Indy version. Current Indy still can be used with Delphi 7.

Comment: Please, re-read what I posted above! Nothing changes. Yes, browser does send form data. No, form data is not in the HTTP *Command*. Yes, form data is in HTTP *Content*. Yes, you do have to read Wikipedia about difference between GET-forms and POST-forms - you do have to know at least MOST BASIC concepts of your business domain when you develop programs, it is inevitable. Yes, your program, when dealing with POST-forms, should read HTTP CONTENT instead of HTTP command which you try to read. If you want to read HTTP COMMAND then you have to use GET-forms instead.

Comment: @The Arioch. Ok then tell me how, using the IDHTTPServer component, I read the HTTP Content? And I'm fully aware of the difference between GET and POST, thank you.

Comment: @mjn42. Thanks, I've tried FormParams, and QueryParams and neither of them contain the data. I went for RawHTTPCommand in the hope of grabbing everything the browser was sending.

Comment: 1) http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdHTTPRequestInfo_PostStream.html  2) http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdEntityHeaderInfo_ContentLength.html

Comment: @Arioch'The The `PostStream` will be `nil` in this situation. `TIdHTTPServer` will temporarily allocate and populate the `PostStream` with the posted data, then free the `PostStream` after parsing it and before firing the `OnCommandGet` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **raw encoded** form data is stored in the `ARequestInfo.FormParams` and `ARequestInfo.UnparsedParams` properties.

If `TIdHTTPServer.ParseParams` is true (which it is by default), the **decoded** form data is stored in the `ARequestInfo.Params` property, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.HTTPServer1CommandGet(AThread: TIdPeerThread;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  FirstName, LastName: string;
begin
  ...  
  if (ARequestInfo.CommandType = hcPOST) and
     IsHeaderMediaType(ARequestInfo.ContentType, 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded') then
  begin
    FirstName := ARequestInfo.Params.Values['firstname'];
    LastName := ARequestInfo.Params.Values['lastname'];
    ...
  end;
end;
```

Note that `TIdHTTPServer` is a multi-threaded component.  The various events, including `OnCommandGet`, are fired in the context of worker threads.  So, if you need to touch UI controls, like your `TMemo`, you **must** synchronize with the main UI thread, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.HTTPServer1CommandGet(AThread: TIdPeerThread;
 ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  ...  
  if (ARequestInfo.CommandType = hcPOST) and
     HeaderIsMediaType(ARequestInfo.ContentType, 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded') then
  begin
    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        Memo1.Text := ARequestInfo.Params.Text;
      end
    );
    ...
  end;
end;
```

Also, 10.0.52 is an outdated version of Indy.  The current version (at the time of this writing) is 10.6.2.5384.

Comment: That's  great, thanks Remy, I've got it working now.

Comment: I ran into an issue using the exact approach and TThread.Sychronize in Tokyo. If the underlying form was not in focus, it would never process the procedure. Adding a timer to the form "resolved" it more or less. Final solution was to put in an idle event, and set a flag to set "Done" to false in the idle loop when I was waiting on one of these synchs. Windows 10.

Comment: @RobbieMatthews `TThread.Synchronize()` is not supposed to be dependent on window focus. The VCL automatically checks for syncs whenever the app goes idle, as well as when sync requests are queued. If focus is now required to process syncs in Tokyo then that is a serious regression that needs to be [reported to Embarcadero](http://quality.embarcadero.com). It has nothing to do with Indy.

Comment: Fully aware of this, just reporting what is happening. However, I can only make it happen under Indy, so take that for what it is worth.

Comment: @RobbieMatthews this would be very easy to verify without Indy at all. Just spin up a TThread or TTask and call Synchronize() in it.

Comment: @RobbieMatthews And, did it also fail? If so, that doesn't match your statement of "*I can only make it happen under Indy*"', since that is all Indy is doing internally (running a TThread).

Comment: To clarify: I can duplicate this behaviour within the IdHttp Get handling method, I can't just using threads in an otherwise vanilla project. The behaviour seems new to the latest windows 10 update.

Comment: @RobbieMatthews although the latest Windows 10 updates did break a lot of things, I can't imagine they would break something so basic to the OS like posting/handling window messages (which Synchronize() does use internally). There is no possible way that `Synchronize()` would work fine in a manual TThread and not work in an Indy TThread. The underlying mechanism to execute the specified procedure is the same either way. Something else is going on.

Comment: Not saying there isn't something else going on. If I get some time next week I will do some more testing, see if I can replicate the problem in a stripped down format.