# Indy HTTP Server ARequestInfo.Params.Text Encoding Wrong

Tags: delphi, indy

I am using Delphi 10.4.2 , Indy 10.6.2.0 .

I've tried this solutions : [Indy HTTP Server URL-encoded request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24861793/indy-http-server-url-encoded-request) , but I guess I am misunderstanding something .

I get the JSON from the Web Application like this :

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  If ARequestInfo.CommandType = hcPOST then
  begin

    MyDecodeAndSetParams(ARequestInfo);

    Memo1.Lines.Add(ARequestInfo.Params.Text);
end;
```

I am probably doing something wrong but my result is still incorrect :

D Karlsruhe / SÃ¼dweststadt, BahnhofstraÃŸe

It should be
Südweststadt and Bahnhofstraße

Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The decoded text you have shown is what happens when UTF-8 is misinterpreted as Latin-1/8bit. If you are using an up-to-date version of Indy, then as I stated in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24875418/65863) to the post you linked to, `TIdHTTPServer` was updated several years ago (after 10.4.2 was released) to handle this issue, so you shouldn't need `MyDecodeAndSetParams()` anymore if you are using an up-to-date version of Indy.

But, it sounds like you are using an older version and should [update Indy](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/wiki/Updating-Indy).  But, if you are stuck using an older version of Indy, then you will have to update `MyDecodeAndSetParams()` instead.

Since you are processing a `POST` request, you are likely falling into the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` portion of the code, and I'm betting that `ARequestInfo.CharSet` is blank, which would cause `CharsetToEncoding()` to fallback to Indy's 8-bit encoding instead of UTF-8.

Try changing this line in `MyDecodeAndSetParams()`:

```
LEncoding := CharsetToEncoding(ARequestInfo.CharSet);
```

To this instead:

```
if ARequestInfo.CharSet <> '' then
  LEncoding := CharsetToEncoding(ARequestInfo.CharSet)
else
  LEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
```

*(I have updated the example in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24875418/65863))*

---

On a side note: `TIdHTTPServer` is multi-threaded, its `OnCommandGet` event is fired in the context of a worker thread, so you *must* synchronize with the main UI thread when accessing UI controls, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  If ARequestInfo.CommandType = hcPOST then
  begin

    MyDecodeAndSetParams(ARequestInfo);

    //Memo1.Lines.Add(ARequestInfo.Params.Text);
    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add(ARequestInfo.Params.Text);
      end
    );
end;
```